# How to fill out a matrix with a loop in R?

Tags: r

```
a <- function(b,c,d,e,f){ 
if(f == 1){
  Value1 <- b * c * d * e
  return(Value1)
}else if(f == 2){
  Value2 <- b * c * d
  return(Value2) 
}else{
  Value3 <- 0 
}
}
```

Assume i would like to analyze the relationship between Value2 and d for `d =seq(1,1.2,0.01)` with `c = seq(1,2,0.2)` and b,e,f are fixed.

I tried this:

```
ValueChange <- matrix(,6,21) 

for(i in seq(1,1.2,0.01)){
  for(j in seq(1,2,0.2)){
    for(n in 1:6){

      ValueChange[n,] <- c(ValueChange, a(10,j,i,5,2))

    }
}
}
ValueChange
```

It should be like this:

```
ValueChange[1,1] <- a(10,1,1,5,2)
ValueChange[1,2] <- a(10,1,1.01,5,2)
... 
ValueChange[2,1] <- a(10,1.2,1,5,2)
...
```

There is an error message: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. However, I have no idea how to fix it. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your nested `for` loop, it might be something like

```
p <- seq(1,1.2,0.01)
q <- seq(1,2,0.2)
for(i in seq_along(p)){
  for(j in seq_along(q)){
      ValueChange[j,i] <- a(10,q[j],p[i],5,2)
  }
}
```

---

Maybe you can try nested `sapply`

```
ValueChange <- sapply(seq(1,1.2,0.01), function(i) sapply(seq(1,2,0.2), function(j) a(10,j,i,5,2)))
```

which gives the same result as nested `for` loop

Comment: Ha ha! I was just about to post the same answer! I guess the only thing is that the OP seems to want the results to be written in the first 6 columns of `ValueChange`, which is otherwise a 21-column matrix. Not clear how important that is though...

Comment: @AllanCameron Haha! I was just guessing OP's intention but not sure the goal exactly. Let's wait and see if OP will provide more information